# is it possible to build a graph having the adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, sage

I am readying about graph theory in sagemath or python,

```
g2=Graph({0:[1,2,3,4,5], 1:[2,3,4,5], 2:[5], 3:[4,5], 4:[5]})
```

if g2 is the graph, then with

```
g2.adjacency_matrix()
```

SAGEMATH easily constructs the adjacency matrix, I was wondering if it is possible or is there some code where if I have the adjacency matrix sage or python build the graph

---

---

thanks davidlowryduda,, Now  I have this matrix

```
T= array([[ 0, 0, 0,  1,  1],
          [0,  0,  1, 0,  1],
          [0,  1,  0,  1, 0],
          [ 1, 0,  1,  0, 0],
          [ 1,  1, 0, 0,  0]])
```

but, for

```
 G = Graph(T, format='adjacency_matrix'),
```

I need this type!

```
matrix([[0, 0, 0,  1,  1],[0,  0,  1, 0,  1],[0,  1,  0,  1, 0],[ 1, 0,  1,  0, 0],[ 1,  1, 0, 0,  0]]).
```

Is it possible to transform from array to the form I need to be able to load that code?

Answer (score 2):

Sage will very happily plot the graph for you if you give it a matrix.

For your `g2`, if you simply type `g2` at an interactive sage session, then it will present you with a plot of a graph. `g2.show()` and `g2.plot()` are other ways to cause the graph to display.

You can save the image using something like

```py
p = g2.plot()
p.sage_image("file.png")
```

If you start from a adjacency matrix, sage will happily make a plot for you. For example,

```py
M = matrix([[0 1 0 0 0 0],
[0 0 1 0 1 0],
[0 0 0 1 1 0],
[0 0 0 0 0 0],
[0 0 0 0 0 1],
[0 0 0 0 0 0]])
sage: G = DiGraph(M, format='adjacency_matrix')
sage: G.show()
```

Given a symmetric matrix, it makes sense to use Graph instead of Digraph.

Comment: @Mathyobani I don't know what your comment means, but I did edit my answer. I omitted one cast to a matrix.